# Jsoup Element changed by calling appendTo on it

Tags: java, jsoup, pass-by-reference

I have a list of `Jsoup` `Element` Objects

I loop through them several times and create several new `Element` Objects from the list.

Something like this:

```
public static Element mergeElements(List<Element> elements, int startFrom) {
    Element mergedElement = new Element("div");
    for (int i = startFrom; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        elements.get(i).appendTo(mergedElement);
     }
    
    return mergedElement
}
```

The method above can be called several times, using the same `List` of `element` Objects.

I'm observing that the returned `mergedElement` object is modified after I call `mergeElements()`.
A simplified example.

```
Element firstMergedElement = mergeElements(elements, 0);
System.out.println(firstMergedElement);
Element secondMergedElement = mergeElements(elements, 1);
// The object has been changed.
System.out.println(firstMergedElement);
```

Is this possible?
Why would `appendTo` change `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `appendTo` attaches element to a a new parent. One element can't have two parents at once so in effect elements will be moved from `firstMergedElement` to `secondMergedElement`.
If you want to keep them also in `firstMergedElement` you can clone each of them:

```
elements.get(i).clone().appendTo(mergedElement);
```

EDIT:
Additional explanation to show what your code is doing:

[image: explanation]

Comment: Can you give a simple example to show what you mean please? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. In the [source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.java) you can see that `appendTo` calls `parent.appendChild` which calls `reparentChild` which removes `this` child from the parent node if it exists.

Comment: Your suggestion of calling `clone` on the `element` works. I used `mergedElement.append(elements.get(i).toString())`. Also, cloning the entire `mergedElement` when the loop complete also seems to solve the issue.